# Simple scoped lock

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've implemented a simple scoped lock like this:

```
public class ScopedLock : IDisposable
{
    private ManualResetEventSlim mres;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor. Expects a ManualResetEventSlim with
    /// state to signaled (i.e. true), so that the first
    /// thread to enter a critical section can execute
    /// the code in it; however subsequent threads may not
    /// be in the same critical section until the original
    /// thread has finished its work there.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mres"></param>
    public ScopedLock(ManualResetEventSlim mres)
    {
        this.mres = mres;

        this.mres.Wait(); // wait until lock is free
        this.mres.Reset(); // take the lock
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.mres.Set(); // free the lock
    }
}
```

It is intended to be used as follows:

```
using (var scopedLock = new ScopedLock(mres))
{
    // critical section code goes here
}
```

Is it possible that there is a race condition between the `Wait()` and `Reset()` calls, i.e. can two threads potentially go in after the `Wait()` once the `ManualResetEvent` has been signaled?

If so, how can I make this better?

I just checked, and there is indeed a problem with multiple threads going in at once. Suggestions for improving this are still welcome. I get interleaving if the critical section is a synchronous method, but not if it's `async void`. I don't understand why.

Update: the intended use of this class is mostly within `async` event handlers, which when called in third party libraries (as opposed to GUI applications), will execute in parallel. This is often undesirable if you want the events to be handled sequentially in order. As such, a simple `lock` will not suffice.

Comment: Can you post the test code?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a ManualResetEventSlim, which actually behave like a ManualResetEvent. Using Set() on a ManualResetEvent will allow :

> Sets the state of the event to signaled, allowing one or more waiting threads to proceed. (Ms doc)

This alone allows more than one thread to be freed between Wait and Reset.

I suggest you may have a look to AutoResetEvent :

> For an EventWaitHandle with EventResetMode.AutoReset (including AutoResetEvent), the Set method releases a single thread. (Ms doc)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

I think your code has two problems, first it requires your upstream code to use it in a very specific pattern (aka `using`), which invites room for error. As [thesyndarn said](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/146906/75787), you should be using an [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) instead so that you only let one thread through the gate so-to-speak. We also need to address the issue of using the code incorrectly...

Since we can't rely on the `Dispose` pattern, Finalizers, or anything else to automatically clean up our code for us, we'll harden the API. I would suggest that it would be better to use a static object and pass in the AutoResetEvent and an Action.

```
public static class ScopedLock 
{
    public static void Execute(AutoResetEvent resetEvent, Action method)
    {
        resetEvent.WaitOne();
        method();
        resetEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Which forces the user into the proper pattern for its use:

```
var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);
//Run other ScopedLock.Executes, or queue up threads
ScopedLock.Execute(autoResetEvent, () => {
    //... Critical Code Here
});
autoResetEvent.Dispose();
```

or

```
using (var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true))
{
    //Run other ScopedLock.Executes, or queue up threads
    ScopedLock.Execute(autoResetEvent, () => {
        //... Critical Code Here
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't see this as an improvement at all. There is nothing wrong with expecting this to be run in a `using` block; it is expected to wrap a scope so the pattern is valid (coming from RAII).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the issue you already spotted (multiple threads can be signalled before one of them does the `Reset()`), you've also got the problem that if someone doesn't use the `ScopedLock` *exactly* as required, `Dispose` may never be called, potentially resulting in threads waiting forever (depending on the scope of the MRES object). What you should do is implement a finalizer (which calls `Dispose`) in your class, so that if someone uses it and doesn't dispose of it, it will still be disposed and the MRES object will get signalled when the `ScopedLock` object gets GC'd (or when the finalizer thread runs, to be more precise).

Overall I don't see the point of this class. If you're trying to synchronise access to a critical resource, do it the normal way (well normal to me) - the class holding the resource requiring sychronisation exposes some access methods which others use, and the sychronisation is internal to the class.

Something like this, to do a very simple example:

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly object syncLock = new object();

    public void AccessCriticalCode()
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            // critical code here
        }
    } 
}
```

Whoever needs to deal with this resource gets a copy of the same `MyClass` instance, and calls the method(s) to access the resource when appropriate. Like this the client code doesn't have to worry about how to synchronise (or that it's even happening), it can just focus on business logic, and the synchronisation internals are handled internally.

Comment: Unfortunately implementing a finalizer isn't going to guarantee that `Dispose` gets run either. As you said, it gets signaled when the GC runs through and finalizes but the problem is that the GC may not run at all (if there is no memory pressure).

Comment: Finalizers... https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/

Comment: @RonBeyer Well true but the point is if you're using the Dispose pattern on an object to free a resource, and the disposable object going out of scope without explicitly freeing the resource that will cause a leak or other undesirable consequence, you should implement a finalizer so that *when* a GC occurs (which for the vast majority (I think) of c# programs will be at some point during the application's normal lifetime - and too often at many, many points) your resources will be freed (if you've implemented the pattern properly).

Comment: Using a normal `lock` block means you can't `await` inside it. I'm sorry. It's my fault I didn't specify this use case in the question. As a sidenote, I don't agree with this not being a good idea just because someone might forget to call `Dispose()`. Someone might forget to call `Dispose()` on any other resource, or they may forget to call `Set()` on a ManualResetEvent etc. Nothing is going to protect you from sloppy coding, but some nice patterns like RAII can make it a lot more elegant.

Comment: @Gigi Fair enough about async/await, I don't really know anything about that so didn't know it couldn't be done in a lock. Anyway regarding Dispose, I'm not saying it's not a good idea because people might forget to dispose it (I think it's not a good idea for other reasons), I'm saying you *should* use a finalizer any time you implement the Dispose pattern and need to ensure that a resource is cleaned up even if the user forgets to do so (not necessarily every time you implement `IDisposable`). I think this case blatantly calls for it, because the consequences otherwise would be catastrophic.

Comment: @eurotrash as far as I remember (and I stand to be corrected because it's been a while), you normally implement finalizers when you have some sort of unmanaged resource which risks lingering around if you don't dispose it. In case of managed resources, failure to dispose them correctly will mean that at worst, they will be flagged as unused by the garbage collector _eventually_ and get collected later - not optimal, but not nearly as serious as the unmanaged scenario. So implementing finalizers always is... overkill.

Comment: @Gigi (1/2) "So implementing finalizers always is... overkill." Indeed, and that's why I said above "not necessarily every time you implement `IDisposable`". As you say, it depends on what Dispose is doing, and whether the object being GC'd will have the same effect. The reason why I think it's important here even though you don't have a native resource is that the effect can be largely the same.

Comment: @Gigi (2/2) If you are using an object to lock on that remains rooted for the application's lifetime, or a static object, then failing to dispose it means it will *never* become set again, and any other thread that tries to access that critical code will hang forever. So it's basically the same concept as when protecting a native resource - the consequences of not doing it means a permanent leak, or in this case a permanently unset event (again, depending on the lifetime of the object).